# Let $C:A\to B$ be a closed operator such that $\operatorname{Dom}(C)$ is closed. Prove that $T$ is continuous.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be two Banach spaces. Let $C:A\to B$ be a closed operator such that $\operatorname{Dom}(C)$ is closed. Prove that $T$ is continuous.

Any ideas?

Comment: how a bout using the closed graph theorem regarding continuity.

Comment: what you have just stated is the closed graph theorem